# Assigning addEventListener to every element in an array

Tags: arrays, for-loop, toggle, addeventlistener

I'm creating a to-do-list, and i want every item in the array to have event listener, such that on click of the item it toggles a class i call "done" which strikes through the item. Here's my code,which doesn't work as hoped.

```
for(var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){
arr[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
arr[i].classList.toggle("done");
})
};
```

Any corrections please?

Comment: You don't add an event listener to an array element with in a loop. You can add evenlisteners to a HTML element , such as a list element and then loop the list element. Share you HTML code let me look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using a different approach instead.
I assigned a class to all the list elements and used assigned an event listener to the class so that every element in the DOM with that class inherits the click eventlistener.